# Selecting all Columns based on Row value in a Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, random, dataframe

> I have a similar df1 with thousand columns and thousands rows. I would
> like to do a random sampling based on a condition in cells in row 1
> (date0) Basically i would like to filter the columns and return
> them and the Datetime index based on the condition if the cell on
> date0 row is equal to V1  and then do the same sampling for cell==V2 and then
> V3..etc.
>
> Then I would concatenate all those samples into a singular
> dataframe. I want to make sure I return the original Datetime Index
> and not a generic Index 0,1,2,3...

```
        abc   def   ghi   jkl   mno    pqr
date0   'V1'  'V1'  'V2'  'V3'  'V0'  'V1'
  
date1     2     5    6     3      2    1

date2     3     1    1     3      5    6

date3     4     4    2     7      8    0
```

To filter I have tried this so far but it does not work
Dataset1=  `Dataset.ix[:,(random.sample(list(Dataset.iloc[0,:]=='V2'), 4))].copy()`
4 is just an arbitrary number for the number of columns to return.
Then I would need to concatenate.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want to include `date0` as part of the column index.

```
df1 = df.T.set_index('date0', append=True).T
df1
```

[image]

Then you can use `xs` to take cross sections

```
df1.xs('V1', axis=1, level=1)
```

[image]

---

***Response to Comment***
This works for using the first row without knowing the row index value

```
df1 = df.iloc[1:].T.set_index(df.iloc[0], append=True).T

df1.xs('V1', axis=1, level=1)
```

---

***Response to 2nd Comment***
`iloc[1:]` is intended to explicity drop the first row.  If you want to keep it, don't include that part.

```
df1 = df.T.set_index(df.iloc[0], append=True).T
df1
```

[image]

```
df1.xs('V1', axis=1, level=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks PRSquared! what if i didnt know the name of the firs indice just appended? Is there a way to get it?

Comment: hi piRSquared. the only thing is that I lose date0 index when we do the Transpose. Ideally i would like to get it back because the filtering should show date0 row values. Would another Transpose for the column date0 do it?        Also, I am trying to concatenate together all the selected, filtered crossed sections afterwards as well.

Comment: perhaps using 'index.tolist()[0]' could help?

Comment: @Pythus that's an easy fix. I'll update post when I get bac to a computer

Comment: oh i see ok thnks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123023/discussion-between-pythus-and-pirsquared).